# Base64 to Pdf export issue AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-puppeteer

I'm creating pdf document using AWS Lambda Puppeteer Nodejs package.

```
const page = await browser.newPage()
page.setContent(html)

const pdf = await page.pdf({
  format: 'A4',
  printBackground: true,
  margin: { top: '1cm', right: '1cm', bottom: '1cm', left: '1cm' }
})

var pdf_base64 = await pdf.toString('base64');

const response = {
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
   'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=downloaded.pdf'
  },
 statusCode: 200,
 body: pdf_base64,
 isBase64Encoded: true
}
```

Pdf is getting downloaded but seems corrupted or not properly encoded. 
While opening chrome shows `Failed to load PDF document.`

But, if i remove headers and export the base 64 & save it to pdf using any online service proper pdf is generated and working.

Even if i open downloaded pdf using text-editor and copy the base64 content and re-generated pdf from base64 using any online tool it works.

What can be the issue while returning.

Comment: Same issue here. Seems to be an issue with Chrome (security?).
Workaround: Set Chrome to open PDFs externally in Settings > Privacy and Security > Site settings > PDF documents. It will then download the PDF instead of failing to open it.

Comment: same issue here. When i run serverless in local, it's work perfectly, but when I deploy on lambda, I have an error "failed to load PDF document". If I download this pdf with `curl` of firefox, the error persisted with my pdf viewer.

Comment: I've having this exact same issue. Did you ever figure out the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'am new on serverless, so I can't really explain how it's works. But I had the same problem of you, and I add this on **serverless.yml** and now it's work:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-apigw-binary

custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:          
      - 'application/pdf'
```

Resource that helped me: https://github.com/maciejtreder/serverless-apigw-binary#readme

Comment: Can this be used for FastAPI, deployed using SAM CLI?